# convert below singly Linked list to doubly linked list

Tags: java

I already wrote a small program of single linked list with add and traverse method in that. Now I want to convert it into a doubly linked list. I know all the concept of doubly linked list but I am facing little difficulty to implement it in my program.

```
public class SingleLinkList<T> {

private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> tail;




public void add(T element)
{
    Node<T> nd = new Node<T>();
    nd.setValue(element);

    if (head==null)
    {
        head = nd;
        tail = nd;
    }
    else
    {
        tail.setNextRef(nd);
        tail = nd;
    }
}

public void traverse(){

    Node<T> tmp = head;
    while(true){
        if(tmp == null){
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(tmp.getValue());
        tmp = tmp.getNextRef();
    }
}

public static void main (String args[])
{
    SingleLinkList<Integer> s1 = new SingleLinkList<Integer>();
    s1.add(2);
    s1.add(3);
    s1.add(3);

    s1.traverse();
}

}


class Node<T> {

private T value;
private Node<T> nextRef;
public T getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public Node<T> getNextRef() {
    return nextRef;
}
public void setNextRef(Node<T> nextRef) {
    this.nextRef = nextRef;
}

public int compareTo(T arg)
{
    if (arg==this.value)
    {
        return 0;}
        else
            {return 1;}
    }
}
```

Comment: _What_ difficulty?

Comment: How to put extra refe. to a node... I don't think this a question where u can  downvote it

Comment: I think what @Idos is trying to say is what is your specific question?  Have you tried something yet?  You are right, this isn't a bad question, but tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I am unable to convert my singly linked list program to doubly linked list. Single linked list program is already describe in the question

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Single linked list program is already I put it as referrence . Now i want to convert this program to doubly linked list. which  I am unable to do it.

Comment: Add a `Node` reference for the reverse direction and then walk once through the single linked list to link the nodes in reverse.

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: This is not my homework problem, I am just trying to learn how to convert my own Single linked list program to doubly linked list.

Comment: @JoeC I think you are unable to help people out here or interested in taking your privileges to either downvote or misleading people

Comment: ...or helping people who have shown evidence of trying to help themselves (which you have not).

Comment: @JoeC evidence is there as the implementation of Single linked lis is already there.

Comment: I gave you an implementation below which should work.  Please try it and let me know any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Node<T> prevRef` field to your list class with appropriate getters and setters and then add this method:

```
public void linkReverse(Node<T> head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }
    head.setPrevRef(null);
    if (head.getNextRef() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node<T> prev = head;
    Node<T> curr = head.getNextRef();

    while (curr != null) {
        curr.setPrevRef(prev);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.getNextRef();
    }
}
```

This method will walk down a currently singly linked list and will link each node in reverse, leaving the list doubly linked.

Of course, you would need to modify the other methods as well, but this is at least a good starting point.

Comment: taking a clue from your answer , I have changed my implementation as below .. but still it is not correct let me knw wht i am missing ... class Node<T> { 
 private T value;
 private Node<T> nextRef;
 private Node<T> prevRef;
 public void add(T element)
 {
  Node<T> nd = new Node<T>();
  nd.setValue(element);
  
  if (head==null)
  {
   head = nd;
   nd.setNextRef(null);
   nd.setPrevRef(null);
   tail = nd;
  }
  else
  {tail.setNextRef(null);
  tail = nd;
  head.setNextRef(nd.getPrevRef());   tail.setPrevRef(head.getPrevRef());}}

Comment: `but still it is not correct let me knw wht i am missing` ... again you are being vague.  What doesn't work?  I believe my logic to be correct.

Comment: when I am using traverse() method it is just disaplying first node i.e 2 only and not others node data.

Answer (score 0):

just add `private Node<T> prevRef;` instance variable to `Node` class, and set it during `add()` method.  I suggest that `traverse()` will receive a boolean (or even better, enum) `direction` argument